# looking for a SIGNAL in tablewidget

Tags: python, scroll, pyqt, signals, qtablewidget

Is there any signal for "scroll release" when scrolling in a `QTableWidget`?

The idea is, for displaying huge tables, to let the user scroll up and down and, when the scroll is stopped, display the visible rows in the window.

The first row visible in the window is easy to capture.

I just need to know how to capture the event when a scroll stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can capture mouse button release, but if you scrolling your table with mouse wheel there is no "scroll release" since every move you make emits a signal.
I suggest to filter mouse wheel and enable user to use only mouse left button on scroll bar.
More about re-implementing `eventFilter` you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080368/how-to-detect-qtablewidget-scroll-source-code-itself-user-wheel-user-scrollb) , but since you're using Python here is my example of using custom `eventFilter` (re-implemented for my `QMainWindow`)to block wheel on combo box and mouseclick on table:

```
def eventFilter(self,target,event):
    if target == self.__ui.comboBox:
        if(event.type()== QtCore.QEvent.Wheel):#block wheel on combobox
            return True
    elif target == self.__ui.tableWidget.viewport():
        if(event.type()== QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick):#block MouseButtonDblClick in table
            return True
        if(event.type()== QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease):#block MouseButtonRelease in table
            return True
    return False
```

this is how to set filter:

```
self.__ui.comboBox.installEventFilter(self)
self.__ui.tableWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
```

Comment: or simply use `self.tableWidget.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.crollStoppedDoSomething)`